# React recreates my component on each material ui tab switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I added a Material UI Tabs component in my application, coding it almost similar to the one in their [Simple Tabs demo](https://material-ui.com/demos/tabs/#simple-tabs).

I'm experiencing, though, that the components inside each tab — that is those at:

```js
render() {
    /... 
    {
        value === 0 && < MyComponent1 / >
    } {
        value === 1 && < MyComponent2 / >
    } {
        value === 2 && < MyComponent3 / >
    }
    /...
}
```

are being recreated (I can trace this with a `console.log()` in their constructor) each time I switch tab losing their state, while I'd expect them to just be unmounted and remounted.

Am I doing something wrong or is that the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour for a component. Before it gets mounted, the constructor gets called. It might be worth giving the docs a re-read if you are unsure of the flow

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

If you want to components to keep state whilst it gets hidden/shown, you can pass through a flag (or `className`) which indicates whether to hide the component or not.

```
render() {
  /... 
  < MyComponent1 hidden={value === 0} / >
  < MyComponent2 hidden={value === 1} / >
  < MyComponent3 hidden={value === 2} / > 
  /...
}
```

The component can then use the prop to update what get's shown whilst still retaining state. e.g. you could add a class which hides it with css.

Comment: I guess that `hidden` is a custom property, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, your components will need to change to handle it

Comment: And, if I'm understanding, so would have to do each component own children.

Comment: You should't need to pass the prop down the tree. The simplest solution would be to add a `<div>` wrapper around the children and apply your custom style to hide the component there

Comment: I found Collapse component in MUI is a pretty convenient wrapper (since you're using material UI)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Because the state resets on every component unmounting. If you want to don't lose the state of the component you can store it in redux or you can set the new state from the props of the parent component.

```
render() {
  return (
    {value === 0 && <MyComponent1 someProps={prop} />}        
    {...}
  )
}
```

and in child component

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     param: props.someProps
  }
}
```

But anyway the best way is to use redux for it.